# Anchor Text within facebook?

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, status

I've just decided to build an application to `stream_publish` to my user's timelines.
Everything is working as intended except for one small cosmetic error, within facebook I'm not sure how to implement anchor text. Such as how the video application posts:

```
the users name followed by "has watched ####."
```

or

```
<a href="#">Anthony Rojas</a> has watched <a href="#"> video</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this:

```
function publish_wall($link='',$message='',$caption='',$description='',$picture=''){
        try{                    
            $ch = curl_init('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$this->Session->read("gid").'/feed?access_token='.$this->Session->read("access_token"));
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "link=$link&message=$message&caption=$caption&description=$description&picture=$picture");
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            $res = curl_exec ($ch);
            curl_close ($ch);

        }catch(Exception $efeed){
        }
    }
```

Good luck!